# Flutter. Como hago en TextFormField para bloquear casilleros con datos

Tags: flutter

tengo que hacer un Registro de Usuarios, y al buscar un Nro de Matricula me devuelve si hay o no datos en la DB, lo que quiero lograr (Y NO SE COMO jajaja) es que si no hay datos que me deje editar ese campo, alguno me puede dar una mano con eso? desde ya muchas gracias!!

```js
Container( /// ESTE CONTAINER BUSCA LA MATRICULA 
  child: TextFormField(
    onChanged: (text) {
      print("First text field: $text");
      buscarMatricula(text, controllerNombre,
          controllerHcp, controllerSexo, controllerCelular, controllerEmail, controllerPass, controllerPass2, controllerLevelS);
    },
    onEditingComplete: () {
      print("onEditingComplete ");
    },
    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
    controller: controllerMatricula,
    maxLength: 9,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.golf_course,
          color: Color(0xFF56bcbb)),
      labelText: "Matricula • User",
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 12, color: Color(0xFF56bcbb)),
    ),
  ),
),
Container( /// ESTE CONTAINER ME TRAE LOS DATOS DEL NOMBRE ASOCIADO A ESA MATRICULA, PERO LA IDEA ES QUE SI NO HAY DATOS QUE SE HABILITE EL CAMPO PARA AGREGAR OTRO NOMBRE
  child: TextFormField(
    enabled: false,
    controller: controllerNombre,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
        decimal: true, signed: false),
    maxLength: 35,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person,
          color: Color(0xFF56bcbb)),
      labelText: 'Apellido y Nombre',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15, color: Color(0xFF56bcbb)),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: En el onChanged del primer textfield puedes obtener si existe o no la matricula, ¿no? De ser así, podrías tener una variable que controle si el segundo textfield está o no disponible, cambiando la propiedad enable.

Answer (score 0):

Para bloquear un TextFormField puedes usar la propiedad enabled y con un inputDecoration darle el estilo de disabled:

```
TextFormField(
  enabled: false,
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
    disabledBorder:  OutlineInputBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.gray),
    ),
    filled: true,
  ),
);
```

Comment: Gracias pero lo que necesito es que se convierta enabled en falso cuando hay un dato que trae de la DB y si no hay datos que se pueda editar y crear datos.

Comment: Pues entonces establece una variable bool en la clase y cambiala dependiendo de los datos que te lleguen del back, si no te llegan datos ponla a true y viceversa.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías generar una función donde llames al método que te arroja los datos del usuario una vez consultada la matrícula, primero creas una variable de clase de tipo `bool`:

```
bool habilitarNombre = false;
//bool habilitarApellido = false;
```

//LO QUE VIENE ES OPCIONAL, ESTO LO PUEDES PONER DENTRO DE `buscarMatricula`

Luego creamos la función para poder darle un valor a la variable declarada:

```
     void datos() async {
    //por lo que veo en tu pregunta, te devulve los datos del usuario,
    final user = await tuMetodoAqui();

    //validamos que el valor no sea nulo
    if (user != null) {
      //aquí puedes ir validando los campos y dependiendo de los que necesites, deberás crear mas variables booleanas para habilitar los campos, ejemplo:
      setState(() {
        user.nombre !=null ? habilitarNombre = true : habilitarNombre = false;
      user.apellidos != null ? habilitarApellido = true : habilitarApellido = false;
      });
      
    } 
  }
```

Procedemos a poner el código dentro de `buscarMatricula`, esto siempre y cuando encuentre datos, inclusive, si ya validas que el dato que retorna no es nulo, solo pondrías la parte que viene:

```
   void buscarMatricula(data, data){
    //...
    //tu código
    //
    //si tu ya validas que haya datos entonces solo pones esto:
     setState(() {
    user.nombre !=null ? habilitarNombre = true : habilitarNombre = false;
    user.apellidos != null ? habilitarApellido = true : habilitarApellido = false;
  });
    
   }
```

Y ya solo quedaría asignarle la variable `booleana` en el `TextFormField`:

```
    TextFormField(
     enabled: habilitarNombre,
     controller: controllerNombre,
     keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
        decimal: true, signed: false),
     maxLength: 35,
     decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.person,
          color: Color(0xFF56bcbb)),
      labelText: 'Apellido y Nombre',
      labelStyle: TextStyle(
          fontSize: 15, color: Color(0xFF56bcbb)),
    ),
  ),
```

//EDIT: Aquí pondré la función buscarMatricula editada:

```
    buscarMatricula(
    String matricula,
    TextEditingController controllerNombre,
    TextEditingController controllerHcp,
    TextEditingController controllerLevelS) async {
  PostJuga postJugaBusca = await DBApi.getJugador(matricula);
  if (postJugaBusca != null) {
    controllerLevelS.text = postJugaBusca.level_security.toString();
    controllerNombre.text = postJugaBusca.nombre_juga;
    //Aquí vendría el setState que tu estás poniendo al principio del widget, una vez valide que el campo nombre no está vacío se deshabilitará, caso contrario, se habilitará.
    setState(() {
      controllerNombre.text.isNotEmpty ? habilitarNombre = false: habilitarNombre = true;  
    });

    if (postJugaBusca.level_security <= 5) {
      controllerHcp.text = postJugaBusca.hcp;
    } else {
      controllerNombre.text = 'Usuario registrado';
      controllerHcp.text = 'Usuario registrado';
    }
  } else {
    controllerLevelS.text = '0';
    controllerNombre.text = '';
    controllerHcp.text = '';
  }
}
```

Borra el `setState` que tienes al principio del widget y el resto creería que estaría bien

Comment: Hola Jonathan tengo el problema que ahora cuando escribo en el campo Matricula, se borra enseguida lo que escribo, si saco el setState que agregaste en BuscarMatricula funciona, si lo dejo me borra lo que busco.

Comment: Hola @jonatan-perez puedes darme una mano mas, del porque me sucede esto?

Comment: Claro, para poder validar el estado de activo o inactivo de los textFields primero tienes que validar si estos datos no están vacios, y eso tu lo logras consultando la matricula, una vez que tu consultas, te arroja si la matrícula tiene el registor de nombre o no y ahí es donde cambias el estado de la variable booleana del campo de texto, obviamente, todo esto lo haces en la función donde haces la consulta de la matrícula que es en buscarMatricula, solo en esa función puedes actualizar el valor de las variables booleanas.

Comment: Hola @jonatan-perez ahi agregue mi código, que estoy haciendo mal? el setState me borra cuando escribo, ya no se que mas hacer jajaja